# Display Value Based on another Cell's Value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having a bit of an issue finding a solution to a problem I'm having in my VBA code.

I have two sheets, in my first sheet I have an unique ID. In my second sheet I would like to display the corresponding value.

For example, if I had a list of IDs and their corresponding values:

```
001 - AAA
002 - BBB
003 - CCC
```

In my first sheet, I have the ID 003. In my second sheet, the value CCC should appear.

So far, I have an IF statement in place which isn't particularly easy to maintain as this list may change.

An ideal solution would be essentially having a table, which matched the value on my first sheet and displayed its corresponding value.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH or XLOOKUP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah VLOOKUP works best.

Say you have it in Sheet1 FROM A AND B COLUMNS

```
A      B
001   AAA
002   BBB
003   CCC

AND SO ON
```

IN Sheet2

in A1 you type the number and in B1 use this

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A1:B100,2,FALSE)
```